# actioncolumn: how to avoid that the action is triggered multiple

Tags: extjs6.2

I have a grid with an actioncolumn.
If I make a doubleclick on a row an action should be triggered.
If I make a click on the actioncolumn an action should be triggered.
So far so good.
If I make a doubleclick on the actioncolumn the action should be triggered once and not three times.

So how can I avoid that the action is triggered multiple

I use ExtJS 6.2

````
            text: 'RW',
            dataIndex: 'readonly',
            hideable: false,
            sortable: false,
            width: 30,
            handler: function(grid, rowIndex) {
                var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                grid.fireEvent('itemdblclick', grid, rec);
            }```


controller

```'grid': {
                itemdblclick: this.openItem
            },```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below hack to achieve it. Keep this code in your handler.

```
var me = this,
    now = Date.now();
// Keep the user from multiple clicks
if (now < me.lastTapTimestamp + 300) {
    me.lastTapTimestamp = now;
    return;
}
me.lastTapTimestamp = now;
// Your code
```